# Undefined reference to inline assembly code while calling in c++

Tags: c++, c

Link [Fast MD5 Assembly](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-md5-hash-implementation-in-x86-assembly)

above given link has assembly implementation of MD5.
when i am trying to call the following code in c with given execute  instruction, it run successfully. but when as i try to call or execute in C++11, i got error as undefined reference to `Md5_hash` function

for compiling in c

```
gcc --std=c99 md5-test.c md5-fast-x8664.S -o md5-test
```

same is used for c++11

```
gcc --std=c++11 md5-test.cpp md5-fast-x8664.S -o md5-test
```

it show error

```
/staticLibmd5/main.cpp|32|undefined reference to md5_compress(unsigned char 
const*, unsigned long, unsigned int*)'
```

is there any other instruction to that in c++ that is missing.

Comment: Please show the C++ code you are trying to compile. This is probably a name mangling issue.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language.  Just because a lot of C code is valid C++ does not mean every valid C program is a valid C++ program.  More than likely you'll need to make some changes to the code as C++ has different name mangling than C.

Comment: In particular, it is very likely that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/9528746) answer applies. But we can't be sure until we see the code you are giving to your compiler.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Looking at the linked code, yes, I'm almost certain that's the right answer.

Comment: Possibly only some `extern "C"` lacking?

Comment: The attached duplicate is somewhat correct, but the correct answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215256/unresolved-external-symbol-c-with-assembler#35359098

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are compiling the code from your link verbatim, change these lines of `md5-test.c`...

```
// Link this program with an external C or x86 compression function
extern void md5_compress(uint32_t state[static STATE_LEN],
                         const uint8_t block[static BLOCK_LEN]);
```

to read instead

```
// Link this program with an external C or x86 compression function
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern void md5_compress(uint32_t state[static STATE_LEN],
                         const uint8_t block[static BLOCK_LEN]);
#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

and it should start working.  To understand *why* this is the problem, see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574420/9528746).

In a complete application, the declaration of `md5_compress` would be in a header file provided by the library that contains the MD5 implementation, and it would be that library's responsibility to put the `extern "C"` annotations in its header files.  This is why you may not have encountered this problem when working with off-the-shelf libraries.

Comment: I don't consider it a good idea to edit 3rd party library headers... If the library author really failed to apply the correct C++ guards, I personally would prefer placing them around the header *include* like in the referenced answer at the end (not nice either, I know...).

Comment: @Aconcagua Yeah, all I was saying is most popular libraries _do_ have those guards and that's why OP might not have seen the problem before.